# Find values common to two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+ table one  +
+----------------------+
|column A | Column B|
|   2     |    4    | 
|   3     |    5    |
|   6     |    1    |
|   1     |    2    |
|   8     |    7    |
+----------------------+

Output
+-------+
|   1   |
|   2   |
+-------+
```

I want 1 and 2 in the output because `1 and 2 are present in column A as well as column B`.

Comment: Why this is marked as  unclear...

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT T1.`column A`
FROM table_one T1 
 INNER JOIN table_one T2
ON T1.`column A` = T2.`column B`
ORDER BY T1.`column A`
```

Here is **DEMO** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72e9a/1

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SELECT sub1.col
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `column A` AS col
      FROM table_one) sub1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `column B` AS col
      FROM table_one) sub2
ON sub1.col = sub2.col;
```

or correlated subquery:

```
SELECT `column A` 
FROM table_one t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table_one t2
              WHERE t2.`column B` = t1.`column A`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code block for your problem :

`select t1.col_a 
  from table_one t1, 
       table_one t2
where t1.col_a = t2.col_b
group by t1.col_a`

Go : [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e61a59/1/0)